# shell script is executed twice

Tags: shell-script

I have this small code snippet in a shellscript to set a password:

```
if [[ -z "${PASS+x}" ]]; then
    read -p "enter pass or use default [test1234]" PASS
    if [[ -z "$PASS" ]]; then
        PASS="test1234"
    fi
fi


if [ $EUID != 0 ]; then
    sudo "$0" "$@"
    exit $?
fi
```

When I run the script the read command is executed twice.
This isn't supposed to happen.
Can anybody help me with finding the error.

complete script: [github (corrected already)](https://github.com/benutzer193/.dotfiles/blob/master/bin/apconfig)

Comment: `read` command shouldn't be executed twice, because you call it one time. And there's no loop it your code.

Comment: that's what I thought :/ . I tried changing it to `echo "enter ...." read -s PASS`, but its still the same. I have no idea where the error is.

Comment: @webKnjaZ I added a link to the complete script. But I think there shouldn't be anything relevant to the error?

Comment: Can you run the script with `-x` option and paste the output. If `read` is being invoked twice, it will show up.

Comment: @Ketan thanks for your help, I just found the solution godlygeek posted (didn't know about the -x switch - good to know for debugging!).

Comment: When you post a part of your script, post a part that **actually has the error you're posting about**, not some unrelated part!

Comment: @Gilles Yeah, forgot to change it, because first I thought the error was in the loop. But you edited the question to the alredy correct code. I changed it to the wrong code (I hope that's correct?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your full script that you link to, you have this:

```
if [ $EUID != 0 ]; then 
    sudo "$0" "$@" 
    exit $? 
fi
```

That's done after all of the options handling and the `read` call that you show in your question.  My guess is that you're hitting this code block, reinvoking the script using `sudo`, and hitting the `read` command twice - once before restarting the script using `sudo`, and once after.

Comment: Thanks, I just found it at the moment. (while using the -x argument)